# saving double data type generates error

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

```
str = dgemp_monthlyshare.Item(3, i).Value 'value to fetch from datagrid
db = CInt(Val(str))
Double.TryParse(str, dub)              
qr = "insert into tbshare_purchase(share_purchase) values('" + dub + "')"' here generates error
```

need to check query statement since their it generates error even after string is converted to double.
I am using access2000 with vb.net 2005

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "cannot convert string to double". I am already converting value into double from string and then passing to my access dbase table, their it is giving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! MS-access need the format of string as below to store the numbers.

```
qr = "insert into tbshare_purchase(share_purchase) values(@share_purchase)"' `     `da = New OleDbDataAdapter(qr, con)' 'da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@share_purchase", 'Convert.ToInt32(str))' –
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
qr = "insert into tbshare_purchase(share_purchase) values(" & cstr(dub) & ")"'
```

Comment: Still giving error as "Conversion from string "insert into tbshare_purchase(sha" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: what is declared type of qr?

Comment: qr is string and db is double data type.

Comment: I got it! MS-access need the format of string as below to store the numbers.                                                              'qr = "insert into tbshare_purchase(share_purchase) values(@share_purchase)"'                                            'da = New OleDbDataAdapter(qr, con)'                'da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@share_purchase", Convert.ToInt32(str))'